# Create keywords from text string - encoding issue for cyrillic

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I was searching for a code that can automatically create keywords from text string. The code below works fine with latin characters but if I try to use it with russian(cyrillic) - the result is just commas with white spaces in between.

I am not sure what the problem is, but I believe it has to do with the encoding. I have tried to encode the string with this

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', '', mb_strtolower(utf8_encode($string)));
```

but no luck. The result is the same.

Also, I included only russian words in the $stopwords var

```
$stopWords = array('у','ни','на','да','и','нет','были','уже','лет','в','что','их','до','сих','пор','из','но','бы','чтобы','вы','была','было','мы','к','от','с','так','как','не','есть','ее','нам','для','вас','о','них','без');
```

**Here is the original code**

```
function extractCommonWords($string){
  $stopWords = array('i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www');

  $string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', '', $string); // replace whitespace
  $string = trim($string); // trim the string
  $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '', $string); // only take alphanumerical characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
  $string = strtolower($string); // make it lowercase

  preg_match_all('/\b.*?\b/i', $string, $matchWords);
  $matchWords = $matchWords[0];

  foreach ( $matchWords as $key=>$item ) {
      if ( $item == '' || in_array(strtolower($item), $stopWords) || strlen($item) <= 3 ) {
          unset($matchWords[$key]);
      }
  }   
  $wordCountArr = array();
  if ( is_array($matchWords) ) {
      foreach ( $matchWords as $key => $val ) {
          $val = strtolower($val);
          if ( isset($wordCountArr[$val]) ) {
              $wordCountArr[$val]++;
          } else {
              $wordCountArr[$val] = 1;
          }
      }
  }
  arsort($wordCountArr);
  $wordCountArr = array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10);
  return $wordCountArr;}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyrillic characters are matched by the following regex and removed from the string:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '', $string);
```

To avoid it, match [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) with `\w`. But you need to use the [`u (PCRE_UTF8)` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for `\w` and friends to match letters from other scripts (including Cyrillic).

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\w -]+/u', '', $string);
```

---

One more thing, the regex `/\b.*?\b/i` is wrong for several reasons. But if you think about it, it could match the same boundary twice.

---

Anyway, I believe you don't need to remove unwanted characters form your string. You're only trying to extract words. You could simply use 1 regex to match them.

**Regex to match words (with Unicode Scripts, including Cyrillic)**

```
preg_match_all('/\w+/u', $string, $matchWords);
```

---

**Code**

```
function extractCommonWords($string){
    $stopWords = array('i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www');

    $string = strtolower($string);

    preg_match_all('/\w+/u', $string, $matchWords);
    $matchWords = $matchWords[0];

    foreach ( $matchWords as $key=>$item ) {
      if ( $item == '' || in_array(strtolower($item), $stopWords) || strlen($item) <= 3 ) {
          unset($matchWords[$key]);
      }
    }   
    $wordCountArr = array();
    if ( is_array($matchWords) ) {
      foreach ( $matchWords as $key => $val ) {
          $val = mb_strtolower($val);
          if ( isset($wordCountArr[$val]) ) {
              $wordCountArr[$val]++;
          } else {
              $wordCountArr[$val] = 1;
          }
      }
    }

    arsort($wordCountArr);
    $wordCountArr = array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10);
    return $wordCountArr;
}


//for testing purposes
$sc = 'Hello there нам для!';
$result = extractCommonWords($sc);
print_r($result);
```

<sup>*Disclaimer: I didn't even read the rest of the code. I'm simply pointing out what was wrong</sup>

<kbd>[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/JHNN49638)</kbd>

Comment: You are absolutely right... That worked like a charm. thanks

Comment: Just one more thing. Do you know how can I exclude words that are less than 5 char?

Comment: `'/\b\w{5,}/u'` ... See **[quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)** ... The `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (it's not needed but it will be more efficient if you use it there)

Comment: Ahh, that was easy. You're a lifesaver... I was about to write a separate script to catch words with 5+ chars only. But that is so easy. I need to learn regex. Thanks Mariano.

Comment: If you want to learn regex, all it takes is reading a couple of pages from the tutorial I linked to. Cheers